# Japanese mojibake detection

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I want to know if there is a way to detect mojibake (Invalid) characters by their byte range. (For a simple example, detecting valid ascii characters is just to see if their byte values are less 128)  Given the old customized characters sets, such as JIS, EUC and of course, UNICODE, is there a way to do this?

The immediate interest is in a C# project, but I'd like to find a language/platform independent solution as much as possible, so I could use in c++, Java, PHP or whatever.

Arrigato

Comment: You spelled arigatou wrong :)

Comment: Yes, but it always depends on what system of romanization you're using - just like you're use of 'u' for a long vowel.

Comment: I was using 'romagi', to further confuse things.

Comment: Well, to fully confuse things.  We have 4 (+?) alphabets we dealing with (hiragana (original Japanese), kanji (uhmm, imported from China), katanana (left for modern non-japanese words), romagi (The english sounding names or the english spelling equivelints (some standardization... I'm not even close to qualifying...), and  of course, english (europo) ascii)...anyways.   Then there are the the are the charecter encodings, at least six JIS, S-JIS, EUC and a much a minor ones.   Slowly, things are stating to get standardized on Unicode, but once you get bad data in your DB, how do you get it out?

Comment: I'm curious because I don't understand much of this: Is this a question about an abstract sequence of Unicode codepoints, or about a particular encoding, or about transliteration?

Comment: @kerrik - I've tried to generalize the question, since I've come across this problems numerous times.  Looking for very real solutions, not abstract.  I'm not sure how much more I can be specific, but... Given a code page or encoding, are there byte ranges you can compare a given character (single-byte, multi-byte or Unicode) to see if it is a valid Japanese character?

Comment: "Arigatou" isn't even the correct choice here. It'd be "yoroshiku onegaishimasu".

Comment: @kef Schector - Without trying to stray too far away from the main point... As my understanding goes, "yoroshiku onegaishimasu" is the formal way (which is default) of saying 'thank you', but 'arrigato' is very common in casual instances.

Comment: "Arigatou" (which is *never* spelled "arrigato") is used to thank somebody for something that's already done. "Yoroshiku onegaishimasu" is to thank them for something in advance. If you want to be less formal, you can just say "onegaishimasu".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

detecting 文字化け(mojibake) by byte range is very difficult.

As you know, most Japanese characters consist of multi-bytes. In Shift-JIS (one of most popular encodings in Japan) case, the first-byte range of a Japanese character is 0x81 to 0x9f and 0xe0 to 0xef, and the second-byte has other range. In addition, ASCII characters may be inserted into Shift-JIS text. it's difficult.

In Java, you can detect invalid characters with `java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder`.

Comment: I think you're right, at the very least, difficult.  In fact, without a reference indicator, there are cases where you can not tell if byte stream is Unicode or not.   But, I'm still going to leave this question open for a bit longer to see what other responses may show up.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do here is *character encoding auto-detection*, as performed by Web browsers. So you could use an existing character encoding detection library, like the [`universalchardet` library in Mozilla](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/extensions/universalchardet/src/base/); it should be straightforward to port it to the platform of your choice.

For example, using Mark Pilgrim's [Python 3 port of the `universalchardet` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet):

```
>>> chardet.detect(bytes.fromhex('83828357836f8350'))
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'SHIFT_JIS'}
>>> chardet.detect(bytes.fromhex('e383a2e382b8e38390e382b1'))
{'confidence': 0.938125, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

But it's not 100% reliable!

```
>>> chardet.detect(bytes.fromhex('916d6f6a6962616b6592'))
{'confidence': 0.6031748712523237, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}
```

(Exercise for the reader: what encoding was this really?)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but I've had luck using the `ftfy` Python package to automatically detect/fix mojibake:

- https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy
- https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/
- https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> print(ftfy.fix_encoding("(à¸‡'âŒ£')à¸‡"))
(ง'⌣')ง
```

It works surprisingly well for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time and / or priority level to follow up on this for the moment, but I think, if knowing the source is Unicode, using these [charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) and following on some of the work done [here](http://www.tonypottier.info/Unicode_And_Japanese_Kanji/), I think some headway can be made into the issue.  Likewise, for Shift-JIS, using this [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) can be helpful.